# How to transfer very large images from a python script to NodeJS without causing lag within the node app (electron)

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, electron

I am working on a project that involves grabbing pictures from a python script (the python is interacting with a camera by calling c functions). The issue I am currently having is that sending images using socket.io to the javascript app is causing massive lag when the message is first received (about a 3-second pause). The images are around 15mb each and are in png format when sent. What is the most efficient way to transfer these images from the python script to the node-js app with no or very very little lag (not lag in sending but lag in the app when receiving)? The way I am currently handling this is like so:

```
socket.on("frame", data => {});
```

Even when doing nothing with the data that is received, the app still lags/freezes for 3 seconds. The python script and electron app will likely be housed on the same machine if that helps...

Comment: Lag in what?  Lag in processing other things in the node.js app?  Or what specifically is lagging?

Comment: It's basically the entire app that lags. Like I can't interact with the main window (or any window) when the message comes in for about 3 seconds. Everything freezes.

Comment: I'm surprised that you get that lag even when you aren't doing anything with the incoming data.  It sounds like the event queue is getting stalled on something that is taking too long to process.  Perhaps you can download the images with a [Worker Thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) and keep the main event queue/thread completely open for app interactivity.  Or, use a child process for the download.

Comment: Is it possible that the Python app is bogging down the CPU when getting the image from the camera?  Also, socket.io may not be the right type of protocol for transferring an image.  You want a streaming protocol, not so much a message-based protocol.  The messsage-based socket.io will have to entirely buffer the entire image before it can trigger the socket.io message with the entire data.  That will work out to be a lot of excess memory management.

Comment: What sort of streaming protocol would you recommend for this? Also, I don't think so because I get lag even when the python script is ran on a different machine

Comment: Well, maybe just plain TCP.  Send a length of bytes to come so the receiving end knows how many bytes to look for and then stream the image bytes sending them in manageable chunks at a time.  HTTP is obviously well versed in fetching/sending images since the browser does that all day long.

Comment: FYI, I built myself a little plain TCP server and a plain TCP client (both on the same host) and was able to stream a 65MB image from one to the other in 106ms so if yours is taking 3 seconds and locking up the receiving client for that duration, then something is clearly wrong there.  I can post the code for my little client and server in an answer if that would help you.

Comment: Also, what does the socket.io code look like for sending the data?  Are you sending the image all at once in one socket.io message?  Are you putting the socket.io connection in binary mode or encoding the data somehow?

Comment: I am sending it all at once currently, but I also tried splitting the buffer into 3 parts and sending those instead and the performance actually got worse. I am not encoding the data, I am just loading in a static picture for now for testing purposes like this `with open("../data/fod1.PNG", "rb") as img:
    fod1 = img.read()` and then emitting it like so `sio.emit('frame', fod1)`

Comment: Also if you could post the code you are using to send the data using TCP as an answer I would definitely be grateful...

Comment: Changing socket io to binary mode in python increased speed quite a bit. Now only lags for like a second. Still too much for my needs tho

Comment: OKAY.... so after changing to binary mode that lag is gone if the python code is running on a different computer. So now the issue is that if the python code and node code are on the same machine (which they likely will be) the computer lags on message interchange...

Comment: Good progress!  I'd say you need to watch the CPU usage of the Python process when it's sending and see if it is hogging the CPU.  When both processes are on the same machine, see which one of the two is using most of the CPU during a transfer.

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure socket.io is operating in `binary` mode so you're not encoding the image data in any way that could make it a lot larger or make the transmission a lot slower to process.

Then, see if you can get any information about the CPU usage from both the Python and the JS processes during a transfer to see if one or the other is overly hogging the CPU.  Properly done I/O code in node.js should be entirely event driven and (if you aren't doing any time consuming processing of the incoming data) should not take much CPU just to read bytes from a socket.

You asked me to post the code for my test app that sends a 65MB image in 106ms.  So, here it is.  It's two apps, one that sends and one that listens for incoming TCP connections and receives.  The sending app, takes a filename as a command line parameter.  All it does is make a connection to the local server and send the entire file to the server, then shut-down.  So, each TCP connection is for one file.  There's minimal error handling as this was just a test harness.

Here's the sending app:

```
const net = require('net');
const process = require('process');
const fs = require('fs');

let imgFile = process.argv[2];

const port = 3000;
const host = "localhost";

const socket = net.connect(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`connect to ${host} on ${port} succeeded`);
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(imgFile);
    let cnt = 0;
    stream.on('data', (buffer) => {
        cnt += buffer.length;
        if (!socket.write(buffer)) {
            stream.pause();
            socket.once('drain', () => {
                stream.resume();
            });
        }
    }).on('error', (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    }).on('end', () => {
        console.log(`image sent ${cnt} bytes, ${Math.round(cnt/1024)}KB`);
        socket.end();
    });
});
```

And, here's the receiving app:

```
const net = require('net');

let server = net.createServer(socket => {
    let start = Date.now();
    let cnt = 0;
    console.log("received connection")
    // socket.setEncoding('binary');
    socket.on('data', buffer => {
        // do nothing with the data
        cnt += buffer.length;
    }).on('end', () => {
        console.log(`got ${cnt} bytes, ${Math.round(cnt/1024)}KB`);
        console.log(`Took ${Date.now() - start} ms` )
    }).on('error', e => {
        console.log(e);
    });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Both apps are just sending and receiving binary data (no encoding involved).